# Read in coming email count

Tags: exchange-server, server

I am new to exchange server programming, How to read number of emails received by person per day from  MS Exchange server in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

Prasanna,

please try below link, it might help you.

[EWS get count of unread emails from all folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687401/ews-get-count-of-unread-emails-from-all-folders)